Inconsistency in labeling of chemistry figures when enumerated in two columns

As I think you can see, the benzene and anthracene labels are further away from the figure, while the rest, even the "testing" label on the second column. Could someone help me format this properly?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{*6(=-=-=-)}\chemfig{*6(-=-=--)}}{Napthalene}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{*6(--=---)}}{Cyclohexene}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{~[:30]-[:330](-[:30]-[:330]-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:330])-[:270]=[:210]}}{5-ethynyl-hept-6-ene-2-one}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{*6(=(-CONH_2)-(-CN)=(-COCl)-(-COOH)=(-~[:210])-)}}{Testing}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}
\item \chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}\chemfig{**6(------)}\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Anthracene}

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{hlist}
\begin{document}
        \begin{hlist}[item sep=1cm, col sep=2cm]2
            \hitem \chemname{\chemfig{*6(=-=-=-)}\chemfig{*6(-=-=--)}}{Napthalene}
            \hitem \chemname{\chemfig{*6(--=---)}}{Cyclohexene}
            \hitem \chemname{\chemfig{~[:30]-[:330](-[:30]-[:330]-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:330])-[:270]=[:210]}}{5-ethynyl-hept-6-ene-2-one}
            \hitem \chemname{\chemfig{*6(=(-CONH_2)-(-CN)=(-COCl)-(-COOH)=(-~[:210])-)}}{Testing}
            \hitem \chemname*{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}
            \hitem \chemname*{\chemfig{**6(------)}\chemfig{**6(------)}\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Anthracene}
            \end{hlist}
\end{document}


